# Import CSS Selector Styles in Another Selector? (NOT @import)

Tags: css

Is there a way to import the styling of a single CSS selector into another CSS selector and add to it or rewrite properties from it.

Let's say:

```
.original_class{
background:black;
color:white;
}
.overwrite{
@import(.original_class); /* I know this doesn't work */
color:blue;
border:1px solid green;
}
```

I can accomplish this by just redeclaring the .original_class and assigning new values (since CSS styles are rewritten from top to bottom), but this will replace the attributes of the original CSS class. What I want is to inherit its properties into another class without having to write them again (duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no.

You could do something like this in your HTML:

```
<div class="original_class overwrite">...</div>
```

This will have the same effect, but you will have to do this for every element you want styled that way.

There is also the option of using a CSS pre-processor, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), which supports inheritance/mixins.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `.overwrite` selector to the first rule by separating it from the existing selector with a comma ([grouping selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping)), so the selector rule becomes `.original_class, .overwrite`:

```
.original_class,
.overwrite {
background: black;
color: white;
}
.overwrite {
color: blue;
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Also, when you write:

> this will replace the attributes of the original CSS class

there is no such thing as attributes and class in CSS, not with the intended meaning of OOP I guess. There are rules, selector rules (to select HTML id, classes, elements, attributes and other pseudos), declarations, properties and values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. At least not without one of those fancy CSS plugin thingies that I wouldn't touch with a mile-long pole...

Of course, there's nothing stopping you having multiple classes on a single element.

Comment: Mind elaborating on the "wouldn't touch ..." part?

Comment: I don't approve of frameworks in general. I write all of my HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP by hand, and when something goes wrong I am extremely well-armed to fix it.

Comment: Well I have nothing but good experiences with CSS pre-processors (or "plugin thingies" as you call them). Saved me A LOT of development time, and made my CSS so much easier to maintain it's not even funny. But to each his own ...