# Can one CSS block use another block?

Tags: html, css

Can I use something like this in css?

```css
.bordered  
{
    border: 10px dashed yellow;
}

form input 
{
    use .bordered;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Or how can this be achieved without writing each css code block to html element?

Comment: Just if you use `CSS` pre-process tools like `LESS` or `SASS`.

Comment: never seen "use .someClass"

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751966/import-css-selector-styles-in-another-selector-not-import/11071806#11071806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fast answer:**

```
.bordered, form input { border: 10px dashed yellow; }
form input { font-size: 10px; }
```

Solutions for re-usable code is to use `CSS Preprocessor` - `LESS` or `SASS` or you can create a new class and call it whatever you want and add styles to it.

**Ten Reasons You Should Be Using a CSS Preprocessor** - https://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/04/12/ten-reasons-you-should-be-using-css-preprocessor

References:

- [**LESS**](http://lesscss.org/)
- [**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: thanks, it would be great if in the future css will include such a thing anyway

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always add class(es) to the input.

---

You could normalize/refactor your classes so that they are more generic (but do not overdo this). Example:

```css
.bordered {
    border: 10px dashed yellow;
}
.smaller {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input class="bordered">
    <input class="smaller">
    <input class="bordered smaller">
</form>
```

Comment: expamle: <input type='text' name='inp' class='bordered' />

Comment: Yes I know that too, but it makes you write much unnecessary code, no? :/

Comment: well, if you are concerned about how much _you_ write, then you should use css preprocessors. If you have lot of dashed-bordered elements and you are concerned about css size, the class is a good solution. If you have just a few bordered elements, then list them one by one. The choice is up to you

Comment: @GeorgianWeber this is subjective. _I_ would not call it unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using CSS preprocessors, you could do it like so:

```
.bordered,
form input {
    border: 10px dashed yellow;
}


form input  {
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

or, if you want to avoid to list all selectors one by one, you could create a class with that style and add that class to your elements

Comment: I know that but, I needed more flexible, reusable css code :/

Comment: @GeorgianWeber Then just do what Salman A suggested. Use `classes`.